# webtransforms for configSource files?

Tags: xml, visual-studio, iis, web-config, web-config-transform

we store some sections of our webconfig in external files i.e.

```xml
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings configSource="Web.Connections.config" />
...
</configuration>
```

Presumably any transforms specified in the web.debug.config  which target this `<connectionstrings>` node will fail.

if i generated a web.connections.debug.config with transforms would the deployment process be able to use this?

**UPDATE**

Alternatively is it at all possible to bootstrap the application startup to replace sections of the web.config from within the binary being executed?

Answer (score 0):

Should you not be able to have 1 transform for the web.config to change the configSource and one transform on the connections for the connections transformations. That way it should be able to find the separate files depending on the transformations.